# Lavaan and semTools partial measurement invariance syntax

Tags: confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I am running measurement invariance in Lavaan using a 7 item ordinal scale. I have been using Lavaan and semTools, and specifically the measEq.syntax command, due to the fact it easily implements Wu and Estrabrook methodology. For demonstration purposes, assume the single factor is V and the item to be released is V1.

My formula is:
`V1_partial<- measEq.syntax(configural.model = V, data = data, parameterization = "theta", ordered =T, ID.fac = "std.lv", ID.cat="Wu.Estabrook.2016", group="sex", group.equal = c("thresholds","loadings"), group.partial = "V=~V1")`

However, I do not think I have the syntax correct for "group.partial", as the loading for V1 does not seem to be released, and this is confirmed by the summary output:

> This lavaan model syntax specifies a CFA with 7 manifest indicators (7 of which are ordinal) of 1 common factor(s).

> To identify the location and scale of each common factor, the factor means and variances were fixed to 0 and 1, respectively, unless equality constraints on measurement parameters allow them to be freed.

> The location and scale of each latent item-response underlying 7 ordinal indicators were identified using the "theta" parameterization, and the identification constraints recommended by Wu & Estabrook (2016). For details, read:

> Pattern matrix indicating num(eric), ord(ered), and lat(ent) indicators per factor:

> The following types of parameter were constrained to equality across groups:
> thresholds
> loadings, with the exception of:

Followed by blank.

Please could somebody point out the syntax error here?

Comment: My first guess is that you are trying to free an anchored item.  That is to say, there needs to be one fixed item in the set of manifest variables to give the latent variable a scale.  Thus, despite the fact you are freeing it to be different across each groups, each group estimation is setting it to 1 (or some other fixed value).  I'll review the lavaan code and provide an answer with specific variables for the values you want to free.

Comment: Please provide a reprex.

Comment: @GreggH Thanks for the suggestion. I did wonder this too, but I also tried for item 2, and the same issue occurred. I note that I was using std.lv=T though, so I could try lifting this.
Thanks Terrence, will do. Unfortunately, my markdown failed to save last night, so I will need to re-write